# "Cannot convert value "New" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: powershell

I am  listing a set of discovered objects and giving option to select any of the discovered objects by enetering the corresponding number using below powershell commands.I also wanted to give an option to create a new object if any of the listed objects doesn't meet the requirement. Here i'm prompting the user to type 'New' for creating a new object however getting below error "Cannot convert value "New" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."" .

````
    write-host ""
Write-host "Choose which vDS Switch you want to select on by entering corresponding number:"
write-host "(it may take a few seconds to build the list)"
write-host ""

$VDS=Get-VDSwitch -Server $VIServer -Location (Get-Datacenter -Name $DC) | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name
$i = 1
$VDS | %{Write-Host $i":" $_.Name; $i++}
$VDSwitch = Read-host Select existing vDS Switch or enter "New" for creating a new Switch
$Switch = $VDS[$VDSwitch -1].Name
My-Logger "You have selected $($Switch). `n"
if(($Switch -eq $null) -or ($Switch -eq 'New'))
{
 $VDSwitchName = Read-Host "Please enter new vDS Name" 

 My-Logger "Creating VDS Switch $VDSwitchName `n"
 $VDS = New-VDSwitch -Server $VIServer -Name $VDSwitchName -Location (Get-Datacenter -Name $DC) -Mtu 1600 -NumUplinkPorts 2 -verbose```
````

Comment: What are you expecting your code to do when the user enters “New”? At the moment the next line tries to evaluate ```$Switch = $VDS[$VDSwitch -1].Name```, but if ```$VDSwitch``` is “New” this expression is invalid for the reason given in the error message.

Comment: if user enter "new' , i want the code to execute the command "New-VDSwitch -Server $VIServer -Name $VDSwitchName -Location (Get-Datacenter -Name $DC) -Mtu 1600 -NumUplinkPorts 2 -verbose"

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between integers and string? The program is expecting a number but entering new is a string.